# How to process messages from where it failed when jvm crashes in middle of camel processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, split, apache-camel

I have a route like below

```
<route id="XYZ">
<from uri="file://{{env:TEST}}/FOLDER?exclude=.*filepart&amp;delay={{delay}}&amp;delete=true&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockCheckInterval={{readLockCheckInterval}}&amp;readLockMinAge={{readLockMinAge}}&amp;initialDelay={{initialDelay}}" />
<to uri="bean:testprocess" />
<split>                                                     <method ref="MethodA" method="split" />
<to uri="activemq:testQueue" />
</split>
</route>
```

I have 2k items in a file to be split, when 500 items are written to testQueue , jvm crashes. How to start from 501 item and write to queue. Currently application is processing 2k items all over again instead of 1500. Kindly suggest

Tried camel gracefulshutodown strategy to process the pending inflight exchanges, but no use.

```
DefaultShutdownStrategy strategy = new DefaultShutdownStrategy();
        strategy.setTimeout(1000000000);
        LOGGER.info("shutdown strategy invoked");
        LOGGER.info(strategy.isLogInflightExchangesOnTimeout());
```

Comment: can you try splitting to two routes, bean:testprocess to direct:abcqueue,  direct:abcqueue to activemq:testQueue?

Comment: @JishnuPrathap Already tried this, it is still not able to save the unprocessed inflight messages once jvm restarts

Comment: try posting in camel nabble website, camel community is pretty active there.